# GoDaddy Hosting injecting folder structure into URL MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, web-config

I am again turning to the experts on this forum for their sagely advice.

I have an MVC site that seems to be operating just fine on GoDaddy hosting. It is however injecting my directory structure into the url so I am somewhat concerned about it.

For example I would expect the url to be as such:

```
https://www.domain.com/c/77/instruction/True
```

Instead it shows as:

```
https://www.domain.com/folder1/subfolder/c/77/instruction/True
```

The Razor code that I am using to render is Url.RouteUrl. Something like:

```
@Url.RouteUrl("ControllerName", new { objId = Model.Id, SeName = Model.SeName })
```

Again everything work fine I'm just  not sure having the directory structure exposed is advisable..at the very least it is annoying...well to me. Not sure how many others will notice.

So would I use a rewrite rule in the web config...or perhaps I don't have my domain configured correctly...or just smile and move on??

Your thought much appreciated

---

Sorry forgot to add my GoDaddy folder structure:

```
Root >> folder1 >> subfolder
```

where subfolder is the folder I have installed to and just confirmed is configured as the root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is here - http://blog.boyet.com/blog/blog/solution-for-asp-net-routing-on-godaddy-shared-hosting/

It's not a problem with GoDaddy, but with the ASP.NET file structure. The link explains this in more detail, but for a short answer quoted from the page

Simply add the following into your web.config’s system.webServer element:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Remove Virtual Directory">
      <match url=".*" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:0}" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

All this does is “rewrite” the URL with itself. This causes URL Rewrite to add the original URL (the one with no folder name) to a ServerVariable which is used by ASP.NET MVC to generate other URLs.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Just got back to this project to try this. It worked!! Thank You!!